# how to just read a string from cassandra using com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Accessor?

Tags: java, cassandra

naive cassandra question, I just want to read the whole column as a string from cassandra using the accessor. Is it possible? Seems to me people are all using data types that are annotated with the table definition :(  I could have had defined a user type with the table annotation, but the name of the keyspace is different in every environment

please help. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call .toString () after the mapper ?

Keyspace annotation is not mandatory.
You can specify default keyspace when creating the session.

```
Session session = cluster.connect("myKeyspace");
```